Set default location of terminals in VS Code per terminal profile
I have a monorepo, and every time I open a terminal, I have to cd to a specific directory; and it's different for each terminal.
I want to skip this step and set different default directories for terminals in vscode.
Something like terminal.integrated.cwd, but per profile:
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
  "My Frontend": {
    "source": "PowerShell"
    "cwd": "frontend-folder"
  },
  "My Backend": {
    "path": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\wsl.exe",
    "cwd": "backend-folder"
  }
}

However, this setting doesn't exist and I can only set one cwd for all.
Ideally, I want powershell (default terminal) to open in /frontend-folder and Ubuntu (WSL) terminal to open in /backend-folder.
Update
This setting works for powershell
{
...
  "My Frontend": {
    "source": "PowerShell",
    "icon": "terminal-powershell",
    "args": [
      "-NoExit",
      "-Command",
      "Set-Location -Path '${workspaceFolder}/frontend-folder'"
    ]
  }
...
}

But I don't know what is the equivalent for WSL.



This setting works for powershell

For robustness, use embedded double-quoting around the path, so as to also support paths with embedded ' characters:
  "Set-Location -Path \"${workspaceFolder}/frontend-folder\""


But I don't know what is the equivalent for WSL.

Use wsl.exe's --cd parameter to pass the startup directory; run wsl --help to see all supported parameters and their descriptions.
To put it all together:
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
  // ...
  "My Frontend": {
    "source": "PowerShell",
    "args": [
      "-NoExit",
      "-Command",
      "Set-Location -Path \"${workspaceFolder}\\frontend-folder\""
    ]
  },
  "My Backend": {
    "path": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\wsl.exe",
    "args": [ "--cd", "${workspaceFolder}\\backend-folder" ]
  }
  // ...
}

